# (TypeError): Cannot read property 'substr' of null | cannot filter dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am having trouble with an error message in R when I try to filter my dataframe. I've tried researching the problem but there doesn't seem to be anything directly related to my needs.

First I had some issues with duplicate row names, which is why I set `row.names = NULL`.

```
 my_data <- read.csv("my_path\\my_folder\\file.csv", sep = "|", row.names = NULL)
```

Then I had some problems with shifting columns, so then I used:

```
colnames(my_data) <- c(colnames(my_data)[-1],NULL)
```

These commands seems to solve the problem for me. However now I cannot filter my data with the tidyverse library. I have tried `filter(my_data$column_1 >45)` and `filter(column_1 >45)` but I get the same error messages.

While I type the filter command, I get the popup:

```
(TypeError): Cannot read property 'substr' of null
```

If I try to execute the command anyway I get:

```
Error in env_bind_lazy(private$bindings, !!!set_names(promises, names_bindings)) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

I get the feeling that this is related to `row.names = NULL`but I'm having trouble finding an alternative method to get my dataframe in order and in a way that I can filter it properly. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all!

(EDIT) Example data that was read from a csv file:
Also I found that I only get the filter issue after I run the `colnames(my_data) <- c(colnames(my_data)[-1],NULL)` command.

```
  my_index|GT|GQ|DP
    1|" 0/1"|67|14
    2|" 1/1"|52|11
    1|" 0/1"|21|50
    2|" 0/1"|39|10
```

dput result:

```
structure(list(index = 1:4, GT = c(" 0/1", " 1/1", " 0/1", " 0/1"
), GQ = c(67L, 52L, 21L, 39L), DP = c(14L, 11L, 5L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: First restart R, read the data and can you provide `dput` of data before changing column names? `dput(head(my_data))` . Also why are you shifting columns btw? Why have you used `NULL` as last column?

Comment: Thank you @AnuragN.Sharma for your reply. I've added example data to the post.

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah for the reply. I've added the `dput` result to the post. I've shifted columns because when I read in the csv, I get an error messaging about duplicated row names not being allowed. When I workaround this with `row.names = NULL`, a new column called `row.names` is added as a first column and all my data is shifted to the left and in the wrong columns.

Comment: What happens if you change the last column name to something else instead of `NULL` ? `colnames(my_data) <- c(colnames(my_data)[-1], 'temp')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because of creating a column called `NULL`. We can rename the column with any other arbitrary name and it should work fine. For example -

```
colnames(my_data) <- c(colnames(my_data)[-1], 'temp')
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this with `append`

```
colnames(my_data) <- append(colnames(my_data)[-1], "temp")
```